# Fetch rows in batches from a table/tables in guaranteed order in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, jdbc

I am creating a bulk load utility in java that will read rows from tables from source database and populate data in destination database as the destination database is empty.

I started with select statement as below: This will return me batches and as order was guaranteed by order by clause. Everything works fine assuming no record with past date (created_date) is inserted while this bulk utility in process.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.${batch.name}
        ORDER BY created_date
        OFFSET ${batch.offset} ROWS
        FETCH NEXT ${batch.batchSize} ROWS ONLY;
```

But later I realize there are some tables those don't have created_date column.

As per the SQL-Server order is not guaranteed if you don't specify explicit order by clause. So I can not remove order by, but as created_date is not in all table this query will fail.

Is there a generic select query that can return me rows in an order taking into consideration that all tables don't have a common column for order by clause OR Any query that can return the rows in insertion order?

Will the following query work? What if more rows were inserted while this batch utility is in progress using following query?

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.${batch.name}
            ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
            OFFSET ${batch.offset} ROWS
            FETCH NEXT ${batch.batchSize} ROWS ONLY;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer... Nope... That said, all tables should have a primary key. Why not simply use that?

Comment: I can not specify primary keys in where clause to select rows as Application don't have primary keys. I just want to replicate whole table to another database by picking rows in batches.

Comment: Why use batches?  Why not just open a ResultSet using a single query and iterate through the rows? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Comment: Processing rows one by one using ResultSet/Cursor will not be an efficient solution in this case as data is huge. Also consider if few rows fail to insert into destination data center I don't want to start over. Mainly because of performance issues with cursors and not bale to use multithreading with ResultSet/Cursor based approach I thought of batches.     
Using batches I can use multiple threads to read/write multiple rows at once and process independently. If any batch fail I don't need to start over just need to process that batch.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as insertion order. By definition a table is an unordered set. Order only happens when you order your resultset. So no, what you want is not possible. What is worse is you may think that it does because it will usually return them in the order of the clustered index....until suddenly it doesn't.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Comment: [Working link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160910015746/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/)

Answer (score 0):

Because we can not fetch rows in insertion order so I changed my query to take order by column for each table that I want to bulk load. It has a downside that while bulk load process is in progress we can not insert into those table. So need to take a snapshot of source database while bulk load process is running.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.${batch.name}
        ORDER BY ${batch.orderByColumn}
        OFFSET ${batch.offset} ROWS
        FETCH NEXT ${batch.batchSize} ROWS ONLY;
```

Thanks [@Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) and [@Jason A. Long](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8233079/jason-a-long) for you response.